Wipe out UBI volume in U-boot
The goal is to erase confidential information from the UBIFS volume.
In Linux you'd use ubiupdatevol -t, but there's no such an option in the u-boot.
Not sure if removing volume cleans up the contents of the chip and space the volume was allocated with. Writing into the volume space should not help because UBI employs wear leveling. I can't figure out the possible solution reading the UBI/FS documentation. Erasing the whole chip is not an option.
Update: the documentation says

A Special case of the volume update operation is what we call volume truncation, which is done by the same ioctl command when the data length is zero. In this case the volume is wiped out and will contain all 0xFF bytes (all LEBs will be un-mapped).

therefore theoretically it may work using
ubi write[vol] address volume 0

but it must be tried and proven that U-boot UBI driver supports truncation.
Update: truncation is supported by the U-boot I have, and writing 0 byte count physically erases all the volume's space.
